# How to replace javascript canas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on javascript and I want to replace the existing graph into a different graph using radio button. I can't make the graphs switch from one another. Can you help me. Thanks

Comment: can you please provide us what you have tried to accomplish such? Thanks.

Comment: I tried putting the same contents of the graph into another method but i reduce the columns into 4 and I called it using the onclick tag.@briosheje

Answer (score 0):

You would need to clear the canvas and redraw it by calling your graph method for the new graph

```js
function draw(color) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.fillStyle = color.value;
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" onchange="draw(this);" name="g" value="red">Red
<br>
<input type="radio" onchange="draw(this);" name="g" value="blue">Blue


<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks but we aren't allowed to use jquery :(

Comment: Jquery was only the click binder, I updated the example to pure js